# What's the best way to use python-syntax config files (in python of course)?

Tags: python, configuration, import, config

My config file is really just a big python dict, but I have many config files to run different experiments and I want to 'import' a different one based on a command line option. Instinctively I want to do import ConfigFileName where ConfigFileName is a string with the config file's python package name in it...  but that doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `__import__` builtin function. But like nosklo, I prefer to store it in simpler data format like JSON of INI config file.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I think I'll move to JSON, just as expressive and less of a pain.

Comment: Please explain briefly why JSON? What is an example of something that's less pain in JSON? JSON doesn't allow comments, right? which seems like a major drawback.

Comment: Another popular choice is yaml, which does allow comment. The YAML parser is not included in the standard library though.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to json. It's [included with python](http://docs.python.org/library/json) and makes a better format overall for config files.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider ConfigParser, also included with python.  It offers simple sectioned name/value items, default settings, and some substitution capabilities.  If that's flexible enough for your needs, it would be a nice alternative.